# Second Time on expanding Row expander in grid, the panel is not displaying in Ext js

Tags: extjs

i have a grid with row expander and when i click on row and try to disply my panel but panel is not displying.Any suggestions will be appreciated

> This the card Layout, On which the panel is displayed when row expander is clicked.

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.UserForm', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
  xtype: 'userform',
  //layout:'card',
  requires: [
    'MyApp.store.Personnel'
  ],
  itemId: 'user_form',
  title: 'Personnel',
  controller: 'main',
  viewModel: 'main',
  store: {
    type: 'personnel'
  },
  height: 500,
  layout: {
    type: 'card'
  },
  // Allow scrollbar (in this example, according to the above height, we should only have horizontal scrollbars)
  scrollable: true,
  tbar: [{
    text: 'Prev',
    action: 'back',
    disabled: true,
    handler: function(btn) {
      var panel = btn.up('panel'),
        activeItem = panel.getLayout().getActiveItem(),
        activeIdx = panel.items.indexOf(activeItem);
      if (--activeIdx >= 0) {
        panel.getLayout().setActiveItem(activeIdx);
      }
      panel.down('button[action=next]').setDisabled(!panel.getLayout().getNext());
      panel.down('button[action=back]').setDisabled(!panel.getLayout().getPrev());
      panel.down('button[action=finish]').setDisabled(panel.getLayout().getNext());
    }
  }, '->', {
    text: 'Next',
    action: 'next',
    handler: function(btn) {
      var panel = btn.up('panel'),
        activeItem = panel.getLayout().getActiveItem(),
        activeIdx = panel.items.indexOf(activeItem),
        total = panel.items.getCount() - 1;
      if (activeIdx !== -1 && ++activeIdx <= total) {
        panel.getLayout().setActiveItem(activeIdx);
      }
      panel.down('button[action=next]').setDisabled(!panel.getLayout().getNext());
      panel.down('button[action=back]').setDisabled(!panel.getLayout().getPrev());
      panel.down('button[action=finish]').setDisabled(panel.getLayout().getNext());
    }
  }, '->', {
    text: 'Finish',
    action: 'finish',
    disabled: true,
    handler: 'save'

  }],
  items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    //itemId: panelOneId,
    title: 'Panel 1',
    items: [{
      xtype: 'textfield',
      name: 'name',
      fieldLabel: 'Name',
      allowBlank: false,
    }]
  }, {
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Panel 2',
    items: [{
      xtype: 'textfield',
      name: 'email',
      fieldLabel: 'Email ID',
      allowBlank: false,
      //minLength: 3
    }]
  }, {
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Panel 3',
    items: [{
      xtype: 'textfield',
      name: 'phone',
      fieldLabel: 'Phone Number',
      allowBlank: false,
      //minLength: 3
    }]
  }]
});
```

Comment: please provide some info what are you really tryin to do??

Comment: I copied your code in fiddle but didnt get any output.Pleaseprovide some fiddle kind of thing.